# S3 Notifications invoke sns topic in other region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have a bucket which I have configured sns topic from the same region as that of the bucket as notification, Is there any way that I can configure the sns topic from other region to be invoked at the time of an s3 event

Comment: Did you try to create a SNS topic in a different region and just use it?

Comment: I have created sns in other region and and through the s3 console when i tried to assign the notification as  sns topic, only the sns topic created in the same region as that of s3 is  listed under notification drop down, not the one which is created in other region, I tried to assign the arn to s3 event but the save button is inactive when i do so

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To test this situation I did the following:

- Created an SNS topic in Singapore region
- Create an S3 bucket in Sydney region
- Configured events on the S3 bucket to point to the ARN of the SNS topic (in Singapore)

The console gave this message:

> The bucket and bucket destination service need to be in the same region

So, it would appear that the answer is **no**.

An alternative:

- Push to SNS in the same region, have that trigger a Lambda function which then sends a message to SNS in another region